# Get database server backup from another server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have two server. Server A is the application server, and server B is the database server. Normally I use SQL Management Studio in Server A to query. I intend to do a database backup (.bak), but whenever I do this through SQLMS, the file is created at server B. I dont have access to do a remote connection to server B.

How do I get the backup file?

Comment: Create a read-only network share on Server-B of course.

Comment: By the way, I'm aware I can create a script to do full backup. I already tried and the file is too big for me. Need the .bak file, then compress it for a smaller size.

Comment: How do you know it will compress? Isn't there an option in backup to do the compress at the sae time?

Comment: By compress I mean zip. Done this before and significant change in term of file size.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a UNC path for the target of the backup.  Keep in mind, however, that the account that the SQL Server service runs under will need network access to that path.  This is one good reason why the SQL installer asks you which account to run the services under.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using generation script. But instead run all in a single script, I run 3 different script (create table, create stored procedure, and data) at a time. I do this because if I run in a single script, I ended up an error. By the way, the script can be compressed (zip) to give a smaller file size.